# Best way to encrypt client side data for SaaS inside the web

Tags: encryption, javascript, asp.net, azure, saas

I am planning a SaaS-solution, where my clients store and save sensitive data on my servers.
Security is a big point as it makes a product more trustworthy, so my thought was that the data which I retrieve from my clients should be encrypted on client side.

But what is the best way (at the moment) for a SaaS inside the web to encrypt data at client side (safe & efficiently).

I am planning to use C#, Vue and Azure functions to deploy my SaaS.

Comment: I thought about a BIP32 key which is generated on first visit on client side with a master password to generate a private key.

Comment: You might want to consider using the Web Crypto API to do encryption/decryption client-side, in javascript.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API for more info.